# How to recover WhatsApp chat history?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, data-recovery

My phone has been running low on space lately. WhatsApp gave me the low storage error and then crashed. After freeing a couple of gigabyte on my phone, I went back to WhatsApp, only to discover that my chat history (for all contacts) has been wiped out. However, I discovered that in my phone's settings, it says WhatsApp is using 70 GB (probably all my WhatsApp chat data).

I don't think any files are corrupted, because I went to the WhatsApp data folder in the "My Files" app and I was able to play WhatsApp videos from there.

How can I get my chat history to show up again in their respective WhatsApp chats?

Answer (score 0):

1. Back up all your data from WhatsApp
2. Add to Dropbox or whatever is your preferred backup storage app or SD card
3. Sign out of WhatsApp
4. Clear storage bins and delete all WhatsApp data, don't forget about junk files
5. Uninstall WhatsApp
6. Clear cache again
7. Restart
8. Open Play Store
9. Download WhatsApp
10. Set permissions before signing in
11. Sign in, and set all usage and preferred settings

All your past data will show on the app side or web app side of WhatsApp, then go and test the erroneous process again.

Not sure if this will work, but the alternative would be to copy WhatsApp to the SD card and have it always launch from there. To move that data to another drive, that would free up over 70 GBs. Always format your SD card before loading anything onto it. See SD card instructions on the web.

Comment: I dont think this will work. Have you tried it?